# Inserting count into another table matching the column

Tags: mysql

I created a new table with Country, Winner, runnerup,third and fourth.

The other table (Original table) has Country, Winner, runnerup,third and fourth. This table country shows the venue (country where the event is held) whereas the new table has all countries participating at the event.

I would like to input the count value of the winners,runnerup,third and fourth into the new table matching to the country column.

The code I use is

```
CREATE TABLE project.worldcup (
    Country VARCHAR(255),
    Winner_count INT,
    Runner_up_Count INT,
    Third_count INT,
    Fourth_Count INT
);

SELECT *
FROM project.worldcup;

INSERT INTO project.worldcup(Country)
SELECT 
   DISTINCT `Home Team Name`
FROM 
   project.worldcupmatches;

INSERT INTO project.worldcup(Winner_count)
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Total_WC
FROM
    temp_wc
GROUP BY winner
```

Original Table (has around 20-30 distinct winners,runner-ups,third,fourth)

| Year | Country | Winners | Runners-up | Third | Fourth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1930 | Brazil | Brazil | xyz | xyz | xyz |
| 1934 | Germany | Argentina | xyz | xyz | xyz |

Count Table based on Original Table

| Winner | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Brazil | 5 |
| Italy | 4 |

Desired New Table (has around 70 plus countries with some 0 count for all columns)

| Country | Winner count | Runners-up count | Third count | Fourth count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brazil | 5 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Bolivia | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

However what I got is

| Country | Winner count | Runners-up count | Third count | Fourth count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Brazil | Null | Null | Null | Null |
| Bolivia | Null | Null | Null | Null |
| Null | 5 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| Null | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please post the original table data in textual form.

Comment: I have done the table accordingly. Thanks for informing in regard to this

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for *all* sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[SQL-Insert into multiple columns by having different select into queries](//stackoverflow.com/q/41886088/90527)", "[Insert Into Table From Multiple Tables Using Separate SELECT Queries](//stackoverflow.com/q/18419374/90527)"

Comment: @outis The answer differ and will not yield the outcome. However, the answer by Fano yields exactly the answer I wish for. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Also covered by the likes of "[SQL, combine two aggregates of same table](//stackoverflow.com/q/43084625/90527)", "[mysql group by single column but aggregate on multiple columns?](//stackoverflow.com/q/21431808/90527)", and the many questions about unpivoting, such as "[Transpose a row into columns with MySQL without using UNIONS?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1851781/90527)" and "[MySQL COUNT() multiple columns](//stackoverflow.com/q/2625212/90527)".

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate query for each `Winner`, `Runner_up`, `Third` and `Fourth` columns and assign each of them with it's respective numerical position (Winner=1, Runner_up=4 .. and so on) then do `UNION ALL`. Make that as a subquery and do a checking over the numerical position with `SUM()` group by country.

```
SELECT ctry, 
       SUM(c_result=1) AS Winner_count, 
       SUM(c_result=2) AS Runner_up_Count, 
       SUM(c_result=3) AS Third_count, 
       SUM(c_result=4) AS Fourth_Count
    FROM
(SELECT Winner AS ctry, 1 AS c_result FROM worldcupmatches UNION ALL
SELECT Runner_up, 2 FROM worldcupmatches UNION ALL
SELECT Third, 3 FROM worldcupmatches UNION ALL
SELECT Fourth, 4 FROM worldcupmatches) v
GROUP BY ctry;
```

After that you can either do `UPDATE` by joining the `worldcup` table (which according to your example is already with `Country` value) or you can truncate the table and do `INSERT`. Here's an `UPDATE` query example:

```
UPDATE worldcup AS wc JOIN 
(SELECT ctry, 
       SUM(c_result=1) AS Winner_count, 
       SUM(c_result=2) AS Runner_up_Count, 
       SUM(c_result=3) AS Third_count, 
       SUM(c_result=4) AS Fourth_Count
    FROM
(SELECT Winner AS ctry, 1 AS c_result FROM worldcupmatches UNION ALL
SELECT Runner_up, 2 FROM worldcupmatches UNION ALL
SELECT Third, 3 FROM worldcupmatches UNION ALL
SELECT Fourth, 4 FROM worldcupmatches) v
GROUP BY ctry) AS rs 
 ON wc.Country=rs.ctry
 SET wc.Winner_count=rs.Winner_count, 
     wc.Runner_up_Count=rs.Runner_up_Count,
     wc.Third_count=rs.Third_count,
     wc.Fourth_Count=rs.Fourth_Count;
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a82ac78197a8a97138c934c5e8ef372e) with truncate then insert example if you plan to do so.

Comment: Thank you this works perfect. Though I am trying to understand abit the syntax and why is there v after the (Select....FROM worldcupmatches). I am abit confused on the second part of the first syntax where you go (SELECT WINNER AS ctry, 1)

Can I say that by doing so you return 1 hence when you sum, you get the value. However, how come when you put 2 and sum you get the value of (1+1) and not (2+2)?
Or does it take into consideration that its count and not adding the value in the table?

Comment: ah.. ok. .the `v` after subquery is the same as `AS rs` in the second subquery.. I'm assigning alias to it without `AS` keyword.. basically, when assigning alias in MySQL, with or without `AS` it's acceptable. Habitually, I tend to not use `AS` to make my query shorter but that's just personal preference.

Comment: As for the `SELECT WINNER AS ctry, 1`, I've mentioned the _numerical position._ What I mean is the numerical value for each position; `winner` is `number 1`, `runner_up` is `number 2` and so on. Each of the query get assigned with it's numerical value to differentiate their position. Then the last one, `SUM()`. If without the sum function, `c_result=1` will return the Boolean result of `1=true` and `0=false`. In this case, if `c_result=2` is true, it will return `1`.  Here's a breakdown of the query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39dd51bed8ebd95962c2cf16251e89e4

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond and the fiddle really helped me to understand alot @FanoFN